# C++ How do I store and retrieve named variables (strings) statically (by name) and dynamically

Tags: c++, dynamic, enums, static, command-line-arguments

I have encountered this problem quite often and did not find a solution.

I have written a program which benchmarks different algorithms. The program selects a specific algorithm based on command line arguments, like

./my_program algorithm_specific_name1

Now in the code I am doing this:

```cpp
//define all algorithm names here on which we want to dispatch below
const std::string ALGORITHM_SPECIFIC_NAME1 = "algorithm_specific_name1";
const std::string ALGORITHM_SPECIFIC_NAME2 = "algorithm_specific_name2";
...
//define data structure for dynamic lookup of algorithm name based on command-line-argument
const std::vector<std::string> ALL_ALGORITHMS{ALGORITHM_SPECIFIC_NAME1, ALGORITHM_SPECIFIC_NAME2, ... };

//usage of command-line-arguments
const std::vector<std::string> arguments{argv + 1, argv + argc};
const std::string algorithm_argument = arguments[0];

//check if given argument is valid choice of algorithm
if (std::find(ALL_ALGORITHMS.begin(), ALL_ALGORITHMS.end(), algorithm_argument) == ALL_ALGORITHMS.end()) {
    std::cerr << "No valid algorithm selected: " << algorithm_argument << std::endl;
    return -1;
}
   
std::cout << "Using " << algorithm_argument << std::endl;

//dispatch on specific name of algorithm because ALL_ALGORITHMS[0] would not be very descriptive
if (algorithm_argument == ALGORITHM_SPECIFIC_NAME1) {
    //call algorithm one
}
if (algorithm_argument == ALGORITHM_SPECIFIC_NAME2) {
    //call algorithm two
}
...
```

As you can see there are two big problems with this code:

1. Name of the algorithm constants is the same as their content (except for upper/lower case) which of course is not necessarily the case but I still have to define two names for essentially the same thing
2. Manually inserting all string constants in some data structure for lookup - so two places for a change which is error-prone

Also I can not enforce the exhaustive checking of all variants.
Of course there are gcc extensions like Stringification but that only solves the first problem and not the second and it is not standard.

I would like to know if there is a solution to this problem.
So I want to have named variables with their contents also in a data structure for lookup,
something like an enum of strings with a "contains"-method and exhaustive switch.

Of course the code above works but it is not a perfect solution for this kind of problem, less redundance would be nice.

Comment: No, that is not the solution as it does not solve the "named variable"-problem as I would have the actual strings like "algorithm_specific_name1" scattered throughout the program and I can not do an exhaustive switch on those. Please read the question carefully.

Comment: I read the question carefully. This question comes up all the time: "how do I access a variable whose name I have in a string". This cannot be done in C++, C++ does not work this way on a fundamental level. This is [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/). The correct solution is learning how to use associative containers. It is unlikely anyone on Stackoverflow will give you a different answer, for C++. Other languages, like Perl, or Javascript, for example, can do something like that. C++ is not Perl or Javascript.

Comment: But it may be possible that someone knows a better solution. And no, associative containers are not the solution, I know about those. Read the question.

Comment: @BenediktWeiß `if (algorithm_argument == ALGORITHM_SPECIFIC_NAME1) //call algorithm one`
`if (algorithm_argument == ALGORITHM_SPECIFIC_NAME2) //call algorithm two` -- Explain why a `std::map<std::string, function_to_call>` is not a solution for this.

Comment: @BenediktWeiß What in [this](https://godbolt.org/z/6W19a5dzE) solution does not work for you?

Comment: Thanks, TedLyngmo and PaulMcKenzie. I don't know why I did not come up with directly using the algorithm-specific-code as the *value* for the map, good use of lambdas . Everything defined in one place, which is good. Thank you!

Comment: Or, in other words, using associative containers was the real answer? P.S. In some extreme cases, `std::unordered_map` would give better performance.

Comment: Yes, but more constructive. I did not think about the right value in the key-value-pair. I know unordered_map.

Comment: I usually use an `unordered_map` if I expect to use the map when it's time critical or when the order doesn't matter. When I suspect that it'll be used rarely and that I may want to present the content to a user in some predictible order, I like using a `map`. In this case I expect the program to be able to list the known algorithms for the user, which is why I went for a `map`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't *have* to do any double booking when using an associative container like a `std::map` or a `std::unordered_map`. You can store lambdas directly in the container.

A map from algorithm name to a function/functor could look like this:

```cpp
const std::map<std::string_view, int (*)(const std::vector<std::string_view>&)>
    algomap{
      {"algo1",
        [](const std::vector<std::string_view>& args) -> int {
            std::cout << "Got arguments:";
            for (auto& arg : args) std::cout << ' ' << arg;
            std::cout << '\n';
            return 0;
        }
      },
      {"algo2",
        [](const std::vector<std::string_view>& args) -> int {
            if (args.size() != 2) // throwing a user-defined exception:
                throw algo_error("requires two arguments: first-name last-name");
            return 0;
        }
      }
    };
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7n6xsco6j)

Answer (score 1):

**edit:** I should say that this is not necessarily a good idea in actual code. It's just a way to do what you're asking for - whether it "should" be done in your use case is up to you to decide.

This is not a perfect answer, because it's compiler dependent. But at least for clang and gcc it is possible to obtain the name of a global function:

```cpp
void alg_1() {}
void alg_2() {}

template<auto algorithm>
std::string get_algorithm_name() {
    std::string function_name = std::source_location::current().function_name();

    // function name contains a compiler dependent string representing the function
    // At least for latest clang and gcc it contains the name of the functions passed as "algorithm"

    return function_name;
}

template<auto algorithm>
void check_algorithm(std::string_view desired) {
    auto algorithm_name = get_algorithm_name<algorithm>();
    if (algorithm_name == desired) {
        algorithm();
    }
}

template<auto... algorithms>
struct AlgorithmList {
    static void execute(std::string_view desired) {
        ((check_algorithm<algorithms>(desired)), ...);
    }
};

int main() {
    using MyAlgorithms = AlgorithmList<alg_1, alg_2>;

    static const std::string_view example = "alg_1";
    MyAlgorithms::execute(example);
}
```

This example is obviously incomplete, but it shows the idea. A parsing routine that will work for most formattings of `function_name()` might have to rely on more assumptions. For example, you could always start your algorithm functions with a certain prefix, so the parsing can simply look for that prefix.

Check the output for different compilers on [godbold](https://godbolt.org/z/4Me9oYaxj).

Careful: 0 optimization has been done! Things can be made constexpr and many potential string copies can be avoided! This code is just to show the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Good old `define` and function-pointers. Oldschool but a lot simpler than most "modern" approaches (sadly C++ really isn't progressing much in the directions  developers want or need).

The macro:

```
#define MY_FUNCTION_NAME_MACRO(x) #x, &x
```

This is a simple macro that expands to a string-literal of the parameter and `&x`. So a line like `MY_FUNCTION_NAME_MACRO(max)` will be converted to `"max", &max` (do NOT do this with std-functions - it is explicitly UB to take their address unless specified otherwise)

And a working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#define MY_FUNCTION_NAME_MACRO(x) #x, &x
void myFunc1()
{
    std::cout << "func1 called" << std::endl;
}

void myFunc2()
{
    std::cout << "and func2" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, void (*)(void)> functions;
    functions.emplace( MY_FUNCTION_NAME_MACRO(myFunc1) );
    functions.emplace( MY_FUNCTION_NAME_MACRO(myFunc2) );
    for( auto [name,func] : functions )
    {
        std::cout << "calling :" << name << std::endl;
        func();
    }
    return 2;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/9nTexa3YM

The "magic" is the macro and the map which has as a key the name of the function and as a value a function-pointer.

Downsides:
It uses macros, the functions all have to have the same signature, annoying to deal with function-pointers directly.
Benefit:
Easy to write, short, works with ancient C++ versions, no template-voodoo

Comment: Here's the same thing, [somewhat simplified](https://godbolt.org/z/E8vGhx3jr).